# Generating a thick spherical gyroid object for 3D printing

Tags: plotting, 3d-printing

I have the code for the spherical gyroid as shown below. My problem is when I attempt 3D printing, I can not obtain the object because the thickness is too small. How do I increase the thickness of the gyroid in the code? Or if there is another way to make the plot, I will be happy to learn about it.

```
r = 2 Pi;
ContourPlot3D[Sin[x] Cos[y] + Sin[y] Cos[z] + Sin[z] Cos[x] == 0,
  {x, -r, r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, -r, r},
  RegionFunction -> ({x, y, z} \[Function] x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= r^2),
  Mesh -> None]
```

Answer (score 4):

**Reply the comment: export  stl format**

```
r = 2 Pi; solid = 
 ContourPlot3D[
  Sin[x] Cos[y] + Sin[y] Cos[z] + Sin[z] Cos[x] == 0, {x, -r, 
   r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, -r, r}, 
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= r^2], 
  Mesh -> None, PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface", 
  Method -> {"Extrusion" -> .2}, RegionBoundaryStyle -> None];
Export["test.stl", solid]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer. Is there a way i can edit the code on the thickness to have several thicknesses of my choice

Comment: @SelamoBasile – Set thickness by adding `Extrusion` as a `Method` option. For example, `Method -> {"Extrusion" -> .2}` makes a thinner wall.

Comment: @creidhne Wonderful!

Comment: Good morning Sir, I managed to write the complete code. my problem now is how do i export the code as STL file or save the code in stl formate. r = 2 Pi;
ContourPlot3D[
 Sin[x] Cos[y] + Sin[y] Cos[z] + Sin[z] Cos[x] == 0, {x, -r, 
  r}, {y, -r, r}, {z, -r, r}, 
 RegionFunction -> ({x, y, z} \[Function] x^2 + y^2 + z^2 <= r^2), 
 Mesh -> None, PlotTheme -> "ThickSurface", Method -> {"Extrusion" -> .2}]           this is the code i have written

Comment: thank you so much Sir, I am doing my research on this and I will be grateful if you write me the complete code. I am supposed to do 3D printing to obtain a physical object. I will be so grateful if you assist me with a complete code showing how I can save it as an STL file

Comment: @SelamoBasile see the updated.

Comment: This solution creates an STL object that is not printable.  There might be an in-slicer tweak to make it printable; however it will be a **very** challenging print since the entire object is built upon a very small base: [See here](https://imgur.com/a/pKMM9N0)  I you are "doing your research" on 3D printing, choose a simpler model, if you are doing your research on the region, choose a different visualization method.

Comment: @bobthechemist, May not be so elegant, but why not slice the object (an equatorial cut) and print two pieces (then glue them together)?

Comment: @mjw I think that would be a very viable option.  What is left to be determined is how effective the "ThickSurface" and `Extrusion` options are.  I had to scale the object > 300% in order to get walls that were more than the width of a standard 3DP nozzle.